# Update a field of a document in nano module of nodejs for couchdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, sql-update, couchdb-nano

Say that there is a couchdb session opened through nano on node.js

```
var dbserv = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984');
```

At the couchdb server `dbserv` can access, there is a database `users` with users that have a field `groups` that is an array.

If I wanted to update `groups` on a user `jim` in `users`, how would I do so without replacing the entire document?

Comment: You can "emulate" this behaviour using [document update handlers](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers).

Comment: @MarcelloNuccio I saw that page before this question, and it left me confused with how to actually create one, store it, and execute it. And since I'm at a loss, I'm requesting an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### CouchDB

To create an update handler, write a design document:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/yourapp",
  "updates": {
    "foo": "function(doc, req) {
      doc.groups.push(req.query.bar); // or do whatever you like with it
      return [doc, 'done'];
    }"
  }
}
```

and PUT it in your db with the id `_design/yourapp`, then GET it like this:

```
http://localhost:5984/users/_design/yourapp/_update/foo/jim?bar=baz
```

#### nanocouch

```
var dbserv = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984');
var db = dbserv.use('users');

var designdoc = {/* The above design document */};

db.insert(designdoc);

db.get('_design/yourapp/_update/foo/jim', {bar: 'baz'});
```

Note that you need to insert the design document only once, you can even do it manually using `curl`, then to update your docs just make a GET request as explained above.

*Disclaimer:* untested and I never used nano before, but it should be on the lines of what you have to do.

Comment: @Havvy, There's one thing of which you must be aware of: using an update handler is EQUIVALENT to: (1) get the document; (2) update the document; (3) save the document. This means that another concurrent update to the same document can happen between (1) and (3), and this will generate a conflict (response 409).

Answer (score 4):

Found a way to make updates, without all _design needs and such.
The issue with Nano CouchDB is that the insert doesn't really provide a place to send the correct _rev that is needed for an update.
Anyhow, there is a work around.
What one needs to do, is to get the _rev value from the _id you want to update.
So you use Nano db.get as the big function, get the _rev value and update your document.
Here is a code sample:

```
 users.get('document_name', function(err, doc) {
        updaterev = doc._rev;
        users.insert({title:'here_ya_go',_rev:updaterev},'document_name', function(err, body , header) {
            if (!err)
            {
                console.log(body);
                res.send('update website succeed');
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(err.error);
            }
        });
  });
```

When the db.insert functions are inside db.get function, it gives us a chance to grab hold of the _rev and update out document.

I know, I probably didn't invent this, but it's important to have this piece of code to grab and go.
Good luck.